# OpenSSL issue when installing scrapy on Python on windows

Tags: windows-7, python, openssl

I have switched to 32 bit installers for `Python Scrapy` (After failing to install the 64 bit installers for scrapy to work). Followed the steps mentioned [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/38490-setting-up-scrapy-on-windows-7).

This is the log when I run the `easy_install` on `scrapy`:

```
Searching for scrapy
Best match: scrapy 0.22.0
Processing scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
scrapy 0.22.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing scrapy script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing scrapy.bat script to C:\Python27\Scripts

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for scrapy
Searching for cryptography>=0.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cryptography/cryptography-
0.1.tar.gz#md5=bdc1c5fe069deca7467b71a0cc538f17
Processing cryptography-0.1.tar.gz
Running cryptography-0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\faizan\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\egg-dist-tmp-vfydke
Searching for cffi>=0.6
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Best match: cffi 0.8.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5
=1a877bf113bfe90fdefedbf9e39310d2
Processing cffi-0.8.1.tar.gz
Running cffi-0.8.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\faizan\appdata\loca
l\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\temp\easy_install-zoguzs\cffi-0.8.1\
egg-dist-tmp-trop2u
_cffi_backend.c
c/_cffi_backend.c(5261) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigne
d type, result still unsigned
c/_cffi_backend.c(5262) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigne
d type, result still unsigned
c/_cffi_backend.c(5263) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigne
d type, result still unsigned
c/_cffi_backend.c(5264) : warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigne
d type, result still unsigned
ffi.c
c/libffi_msvc\ffi.c(122) : warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
prep_cif.c
types.c
win32.c

Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\_cffi_backend.lib and object
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\_cffi_backend.exp

Installed c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.
1\cffi-0.8.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Searching for pycparser
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
Best match: pycparser 2.10
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.t
ar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f
Processing pycparser-2.10.tar.gz
Running pycparser-2.10\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\faizan\appdata\
local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\temp\easy_install-ngu9w1\pycpars
er-2.10\egg-dist-tmp-2uhfme
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

Installed c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.
1\pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg
_cffi__xcfd0a060xfba2f231.c
   Creating library c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\crypt
ography-0.1\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__pycache__\Release\cryptography\hazm
at\primitives\__pycache__\_cffi__xcfd0a060xfba2f231.lib and object c:\users\faiz
an\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\cryptography\hazmat\p
rimitives\__pycache__\Release\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__pycache__\_cffi__
xcfd0a060xfba2f231.exp
_cffi__x5fea2bacx4a8b9ec1.c
cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__pycache__\_cffi__x5fea2bacx4a8b9ec1.c(218) : wa
rning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'uint8_t', possible los
s of data
   Creating library c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\crypt
ography-0.1\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__pycache__\Release\cryptography\hazm
at\primitives\__pycache__\_cffi__x5fea2bacx4a8b9ec1.lib and object c:\users\faiz
an\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\cryptography\hazmat\p
rimitives\__pycache__\Release\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\__pycache__\_cffi__
x5fea2bacx4a8b9ec1.exp
_cffi__xd9dc3d0ax8cb54b0a.c
cryptography\hazmat\bindings\__pycache__\_cffi__xd9dc3d0ax8cb54b0a.c(165) : fata
l error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/asn1.h': No such file or direc
tory
error: c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-myikuq\cryptography-0.1\c
ffi-0.8.1-py2.7-win32.egg\_cffi_backend.pyd: Access is denied
```

I have tried every post answer or tutorial for that matter.. Any solutions to get over this? I am on a 64 bit windows machine

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue but on Windows XP.

To solve the openssl/asn1.h no such file issue check your `LIB` and `INCLUDE` system variables.

In Windows XP you can do this from the CMD prompt window with the following commands:

`SET LIB`

`SET INCLUDE`

They should include the lib and include folders of the OpenSSL directory. On my machine:

`SET LIB
C:\OpenSSL-win32\lib;etc;etc;etc`

`SET INCLUDE
C:\OpenSSL-win32\include;etc;etc`

You can add to the system variables like this:

`SET LIB=C:\OPenSSL-win32\lib;%LIB%`

This won't cure the access is denied issue I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess its too late for this.. This is what I tried: `Switch to Ubuntu->Setup scrapy->save your time`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this thread at a later date:

I had incredible difficulties getting Scrapy to install with easy_install on Python 2.7.  The cryptography module in particular was impossible to install.

I installed pip using the information found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Afterwards a simple `pip install scrapy` and I was in business.